# How can I significantly improve the speed of nested loops?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have tried searching online but haven't found anything too useful

I am currently trying to loop through multiple nested loops to find values:

```
for i in range(10):
    val = 0
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
            for l in range(10):
                for m in range(10):
                    for n in range(10):
                        if i != j:
                            val += x[k, l, m, n] * r[k, i] * r[l, i] * r[m, j] * r[n, j]
    values.append(val)
```

where `x` is a `(10, 10, 10, 10)` array and `r` is `(10, 10)` array.

I feel as though there should be a substantially quicker solution than to iterate through them.

How can I speed up these nested loops?

Edit:

I am looking for a way to speed up nest loops OR a way to rewrite the script such that it improves the speed.

Comment: If your only condition is `if i != j:`, shouldn't you do `if i == j: continue` in the `for j` loop?

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that should be expressible with `einsum`, but I really don't know how to actually use that function, haha. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html  What is this calculating exactly?  A simple way to visually simplify your code would be with `itertools.product`, but that shouldn't have a large performance impact.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what your code _does_. Can it be generalised as a matrix operation?

Comment: @AKX that is true. Good point

Comment: @roganjosh this code calculates loss and returns an integer.

Comment: Loss of what? We don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @roganjosh The problem I'm trying to solve is speeding up nested loops. The fact of what it calculates is not relevant since the loops just index elements of arrays and return a scalar. Determining how to speed nested loops can be a general problem.

Comment: In `numpy` we speed up loops by moving them from python code to compiled `numpy` methods.  For a start move the `i!=j` test to start of the `j` loop, and do the rest with proper `numpy` broadcasting.  If `broadcasting` isn't familiar, you haven't read enough `numpy` basics to tackle this kind of problem.

Comment: @user16573587 if you're not going to entertain the idea that some of this might be a generalised operation, and it _has_ to be a 6-layer nested loop, then the clear answer is "you're doomed". You could try compile it with `numba`, I guess, but I really would recommend that you reconsider the approach first

Comment: @hpaulj Can you explain how you would reduce the four for loops? Prior to asking the question I was looking at broadcasting, but I did not find much information to help me.

Comment: `x *  r[:, i,None,None,None] * r[:, i,None,None] * r[:, j,None] * r[:, j]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample calc:

```
In [76]: x = np.random.rand( 10, 10, 10, 10); r=np.random.rand(10, 10 )
In [77]: values=[]
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     val = 0
    ...:     for j in range(10):
    ...:         for k in range(10):
    ...:             for l in range(10):
    ...:                 for m in range(10):
    ...:                     for n in range(10):
    ...:                         if i != j:
    ...:                             val += x[k, l, m, n] * r[k, i] * r[l, i] * r[m, j] * r[n, j]
    ...:     values.append(val)
    ...:
```

I didn't time this, but there was a noticeable lag.

```
In [78]: values
Out[78]: 
[2405.069869674815,
 1906.3583547360959,
 1934.09600942877,
 1583.4551649741236,
 2441.8509094338756,
 2018.3416769619837,
 2508.333484796075,
 1664.3574504516193,
 2889.949142416882,
 1914.4720528808432]
```

Replacing the inner 4 loops with broadcasted arrays:

```
In [79]: values=[]
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     val = 0
    ...:     for j in range(10):
    ...:        if i != j:
    ...:           temp = x *  r[:, i,None,None,None] * r[:, i,None,None] * r[:, j,None] * r[:, j]
    ...:           val += temp.sum()
    ...:     values.append(val)
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [80]: values
Out[80]: 
[2405.0698696748414,
 1906.3583547360881,
 1934.0960094287668,
 1583.4551649741336,
 2441.8509094339124,
 2018.3416769619737,
 2508.3334847960673,
 1664.3574504516007,
 2889.9491424168923,
 1914.4720528808484]
```

Same values, and definitely faster.

With some more thought I could probably replace the `i` and `j` loops, but the `i!=j` step makes that a bit harder.  But this is a good first step.

`%%timeit` loops:

```
1.22 s ± 2.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
10.8 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If I define a utility function:

```
def foo(x,i,j):
    temp =  x *  r[:, i,None,None,None] * r[:, i,None,None] * r[:, j,None] * r[:, j]
    return temp.sum()
```

then

```
[sum([foo(x,i,j) for j in range(10)])-foo(x,i,i) for i in range(10)]
```

produces the values without the `i!=j` test.  It's a bit slower, but I can probably tweak the `foo` to handle array values for `j`, and thus eliminate the `j` loop.  But more on that later.

Comment: This is great thank you. Do you have a reference so I could understand a bit more about how the indexing works for your first solution?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

The first point you have to take care about is accessing a member from an array is done by indirect access.
For example add rki = r[k, i]  in 3rd nested loop and use Rki directly in your sum.

Comment: do you have a reference that discussed improving speed by indirectly referencing?

Comment: r[k, i] is already an indirect reference. You access an element of a two dimensional array. Your starting point is head of the array. But this value already set on third loop. If you do rki=r[k, i] and use rki you will be able to access memory more efficiently (or python interpreter is optimizing this for you). There are some more such optimization possibility. Slicing x array at each step may also help.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you reduce number of indirect access.
For example add rki = r[k, i]  in 3rd nested loop and use Rki directly in your sum...and so on.